# How do I get my Visual Studio Test Suite web test to iterate over my data source?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, automated-tests, load-testing

I have Visual Studio web test attached nicely to a data source, but I need to be able to iterate over each entry in the data source. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/visualstudionetadd-ins/article.php/c12645__2/) seems to Discuss something quite like what you're talking about.
Good luck.
Ola

**EDIT:** From the linked article, your DataSource is exposed to your test via an attribute.

```
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient",
    "Data Source=VSTS;Initial Catalog=ContactManagerWebTest;
    Integrated Security=True", "ValidContactInfo",
    DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod()]
```

There are several other DataSources you can link to, for example CSV, or even Parameters of a Test Case in TFS. Be sure to include the `DataAccessMethod.Sequential`. If there are multiple rows in the table indicated by the `DataSourceAttribute`, then each test run will have `TestContext.DataRow` pointing to the current row/iteration for the test.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to select "Run test(pause before starting)"

Then when the test opens up, click the little link that says "Edit run settings"

A dialog boxes opens allowing you to choose "One run per datasource row"

Answer (score 1):

Open Local.testsettings file from solution explorer and go to Web Test -> Select "One run per data source now" option. That's it.